# Retrieving an apps Firebase BEARER token?

Tags: android, firebase

App A uses Firebase. App A generates a bearer token upon login.
Is there any way I can view the bearer token stored that app A uses with the assumption that the phone is rooted?

Particularly interested where Firebase stores the token on the users device